# added `acts_as_list` to gemfile, rails gives error :`bundler: failed to load command: rails` when running rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, acts-as-list

I added the gem `acts_as_list`to my gemfile. Now when I run `bundle exec rails s` the server crashes and gives the error : `bundler: failed to load command: rails (/Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rails)`

here are the first lines in the `product.rb`model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_list :scope => :category, :label
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :label

has_many :product_items, :dependent => :destroy

 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, can please someone help me?

here is the whole console output:

```
    hal@hals-iMac page (master) $ bundle exec rails s
Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

In Rails 4, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are versioned
like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

Here's how to upgrade:

  bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
  rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
  git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control

You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
generate it and add it to source control:

  bundle binstubs some-gem-name
  git add bin/new-executable

WARNING: Skipping key "SMTP_ADDRESS". Already set in ENV.
WARNING: Skipping key "SMTP_USER". Already set in ENV.
WARNING: Skipping key "SMTP_PASSWORD". Already set in ENV.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
bundler: failed to load command: rails (/Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rails)
SyntaxError: /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/page/app/models/product.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
  /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/page/app/admin/product.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/lib/active_admin/application.rb:216:in `block in load'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/lib/active_admin/error.rb:41:in `capture'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/lib/active_admin/application.rb:216:in `load'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/lib/active_admin/application.rb:208:in `block in load!'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/lib/active_admin/application.rb:208:in `each'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/lib/active_admin/application.rb:208:in `load!'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/lib/active_admin/application.rb:230:in `routes'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/lib/active_admin.rb:79:in `routes'
  /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/page/config/routes.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `eval_block'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
  /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/page/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/page/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/page/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/page/config.ru:in `new'
  /Users/dadi/Documents/Vefir/stores/page/config.ru:in `<main>'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:45:in `require'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:45:in `block in exec_app_rails'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34:in `loop'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34:in `exec_app_rails'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/bin/rails:9:in `require'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rails:23:in `load'
  /Users/dadi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rails:23:in `<top (required)>'
hal@hals-iMac page (master) $
```

Comment: What do the first five lines of your `app/models/product.rb` file look like?

Comment: I added them to the question, please see the edit I made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not acceptable Ruby format:

```
acts_as_list :scope => :category, :label
```

You should pass it as an array

```
acts_as_list :scope => [:category, :label]
```